# Weakly Dependent Time Series | Common Error

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

I am watching a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xJ8mT6gZb4&t=1m24s), that mentions for the following time series:

$x_t=\epsilon_t+\theta\epsilon_{t-1}$

$\textrm{Corr}(x_t,x_{t-1})≠0$

Then it mentions if we have anything greater then 1 such as $x_{t-2}$ then $\textrm{Corr}(x_t,x_{t-2})=0$ because $x_{t-2}$ doesnt share any common erros with $x_t$ now my question is : if the error is gaussian or a white noise then isnt any $x_{t-\tau}$ correlated with $x_t$?

Comment: Hi: Note that the terms in $x_{t-2}$ are totally independent of the terms in $x_t$ so, after lag 1, there's no autocorrelation.

Comment: Hi: I see and makes sense now. thanks!